# How can I import a set of OBJ files that represent animation frames for a mesh?

Tags: animation, import, conversion

We need to convert a 4D (multi frame volumetric data) medical scan to an animated 3D mesh, for use in realtime 3D rendering.

Some 3rd party medical software we use can extract polygonal meshes for each frame but it has no animation support - if the input file has 10 frames it will export 10 OBJ files describing the mesh in each frame.

It *can* guarantee the meshes are topologically identical i.e. it creates the mesh then deforms copies for each frame, so the 10 OBJ files are deformations of the same mesh, not 10 separate meshes which could be different structure.

This is really inefficient for our rendering purposes (WebGL) where we'd rather load a keyframe animation in format like FBX or glTF than have to load 10 meshes and toggle between them.

Is this something Blender can do? It's akin to creating a video from a bunch of image files representing each frame.

Comment: What format do you have the point clouds in?

Comment: It's DICOM data but I'm not sure why that's relevant. We've already chosen the tool used to deal with that side of things.